# How to extract wind speed and wind direction from Windguru Spot service?

Tags: javascript

Windguru offers a service of providing acurate wind speed and wind direction at certain sites of interest to windsurfres and kitesurfers, an example being "http://www.windguruspot.cz/254".  I would like to be able to extract these two variables automatically, perhaps using "wget" or a similar application, generating a local file containing their values.

Inspecting the source file at the above URL it appears to me that it in turn accesses the URL "http://www.windguru.cz/js/pak/wgs.spot.min.js" which provides for the values I am looking for.  However the source of the later javascript file is so terribly, and probably also intentionally complicated that I cannot make anything of it.

Comment: They don't want you to: http://www.windguru.cz/int/help_index.php?sec=terms

Comment: I am not a specialist in the legal aspects of the web, but in case I am proposing something illegal, please ignore my question.  On the other hand I am curious to understand to what extent a website has the right to limit the ways in which people use the information they provide, especially with regards to the sentence "It is forbidden to download website content by automated scripts".

Comment: Regardless, they don't want you scraping data from their site. It's not an API service. You could end up doing all the work to get the data, then they change one little thing and your data scrape is broken. It might be much better (and easier) for you to look into weather API services that have the data you need. Example: https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: Windsurfers need better weather reports than those provided by the usual weather services.  An anemometer placed on a post on the water as close as possible to the sailing site, reporting wind direction as well as average, min and max wind speed is what we usually need.  But, alas, maybe I am asking for too much.  In any case, thanks very much "Bitwise Creative", your comments were very helpful to illustrate the hurdles faced by my project.

Comment: After benefiting from @Javier 's answer till now the API site now refuses my connections so I am back at square one. I would therefore reformulate my question as to how could I automatically dump ALL of the information you get when you access a site such as "beta.windguru.cz/station/166"; in a regular browser. Mind you that wget does not follow all internal links in that page, some of which lead to the most important information I'm looking for which is wind speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[API Documentation](http://stations.windguru.cz/json_api_stations.html)

[Example](https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_current&id_station=87&date_format=Y-m-d+H%3Ai%3As+T)

Returns:

```
{"wind_avg":10.87,"wind_max":11.84,"wind_min":9.9,"wind_direction":135,"temperature":26.1,"mslp":1028.6,"rh":65,"datetime":"2015-12-30 15:02:33 ART","unixtime":1451498553,"error_details":""}
```

Comment: Add content of links in your answer and not just links in case link breaks in future.

Comment: Dear Javier, this is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Dear @Javier,  I am sorry for my previous lack of knowledge about the system  at StackOverflow which in turn caused me to neglect accepting your very good answer.  Coming back here I have just done it.

Comment: this will not work for stations with password (e.g. station with id 270 returns error: {"return":"error","message":"Unauthorized API access!"})

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I finally found a partial solution to my question which may be worth sharing.  Using the utility *wkhtmltopdf* (http://wkhtmltopdf.org) I can generate a pdf file from the page I am interested in (https://beta.windguru.cz/station/166), and in turn I can use *pdftotext* to extract the info I need.  Unfortunately wkhtmltopdf still needs some polishing before I can use it: apparently, besides the main version there is also a *static* version.  The main version works well enough to enable me to get part of the info (wind speed, but not wind direction) but it only works under X.  The static version, on the other hand, runs in a normal terminal but the generated pdf file lacks all relavant information.

Comment: You can scrape the site content instead of going through the trouble of making it a PDF first, then going back to text and trying to parse that. There's a great Python library called BeautifulSoup that may be just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This run

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# sudo apt install BeautifulSoup
# sudo apt-get install python-paramiko
# sudo apt-get install python-pip
# sudo pip install requests --upgrade 
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import datetime
import paramiko
import getpass
import signal
import sys
import os
station = sys.argv[1]
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'}
from lxml import etree

url1='https://www.windguru.cz/station/' + station
url2='https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_current&id_station=' + station

headers = {'Referer' : url1 }    
r = requests.get( url2, headers = headers).json()

speed=r['wind_avg']

direction=r['wind_direction']
print "{:.1f}".format(speed), "{:.1f}".format(direction)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import sys

station = sys.argv[1]

url1='https://www.windguru.cz/station/' + station
url2='https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_current&id_station=' + station

headers = {'Referer' : url1 }
r = requests.get( url2, headers = headers).json()

speed=r['wind_avg']
direction=r['wind_direction']

print "{:.1f}".format(speed), "{:.1f}".format(direction)
sys.exit()
```

idea get here
[can't scape a value from Beautifulsoup in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331333/cant-scape-a-value-from-beautifulsoup-in-python)