# can't scape a value from Beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am creating a website where I display the current wind. when I go to https://www.windguru.cz/station/219 (and click on inspect element at the max:{wind}) I can see this:

```
<span class="wgs_wind_max_value">12</span>
```

the 12 is the value I need but when I try to scrape it with bs4 and requests, this appears as output:

```
<span class="wgs_wind_max_value"></span>
```

as you can see there is no '12' value.
can someone help me with that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.windguru.cz/3323')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all("span",{"class","wgs_wind_max_value"})
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same API as page does to get json to populate those values. Notice the querystring construction passed to the API.

```
import requests

headers = {'Referer' : 'https://www.windguru.cz/station/219'}    
r = requests.get('https://www.windguru.cz/int/iapi.php?q=station_data_current&id_station=219&date_format=Y-m-d%20H%3Ai%3As%20T&_mha=f4d18b6c', headers = headers).json()
print(r)
print(r['wind_max'])
```